# How to deploy Polymer starter kit 3 through Firebase hosting?

Tags: firebase, polymer, hosting, polymer-starter-kit

I'm setting up a new project, basically for learning the purpose, based on Firebase services and especially Firebase hosting.

I already set up my Firebase project (including Hosting, Cloudstore, and storage) and now I would like to deploy Polymer starter kit 3 in there.

This is what I did so far:

```
sudo npm install npm@latest -g
firebase login --no-localhost
sudo npm install -g firebase-tools
mkdir /home/myuser/myproject
sudo chown -R $USER:$GROUP /home/myuser/myproject
sudo chown -R $USER:$GROUP /home/myuser/myproject
cd /home/myuser/myproject
firebase init
```

Then I tried to install Polymer cli and init polymer-3-starter-kit:

```
sudo npm install -g polymer-cli --unsafe-perm
polymer init polymer-3-starter-kit
```

Finally, I ran *firebase deploy* from there.

Unfortunately, this is not the right way to do and I was wondering if some of you can help me kick this out!

I would like to have pieces of advice about how to articulate my Firebase project, or which documentation could help regarding Firebase and Polymer projects.

Thank you very much in advance!